# Multiple AJAX functions

Tags: ajax, function

I am trying to add an ajax function to a script that does 2 things essentially:

Step 1: Determine if it needs to search for users or create a new one
Step 2: Based on selection 1, it will either go to the selected script (that part works) or call a new function (that part doesn't work, yet).  Now, I know the 2nd function itself works perfectly as I called it directly in the anchor tag and had no issues, so it has to be in how I am trying to all it witin the function itself.  here's what I have so far:

```
function changecm(){
var txt = 'Select An Option To Continue:<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="type" value="search" style="font-size:22px;"><br>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="type" value="create" style="font-size:22px;">';

$.prompt(txt,{ 
    buttons:{Confirm:true, Cancel:false},
    submit: function(v,m,f){
        var flag = true;
        if (v) { }
        return flag;
    },
    callback: function(v,m,f){

        if(v){      
        var type = f.type;
            if(type == 'create'){
                $.post('changecm',{type:type},
                       function(data){
                       $("div#customer").html(data);
                       }
                );
            }
            else{
            function(changecmnow);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

}

That's function 1.  Here's function 2:

```
function changecmnow(){
var txt = 'Enter the first name, last name, or telephone number of the customer to limit your results:<br>
<input type="text" name="terms" id="terms" style="font-size:22px; width:400px;">';

$.prompt(txt,{ 
    buttons:{Confirm:true, Cancel:false},
    submit: function(v,m,f){
        var flag = true;
        if (v) { }
        return flag;
    },
    callback: function(v,m,f){

        if(v){      
        var terms = f.terms;
            $.post('changecm',{terms:terms},
                   function(data){
                   $("div#customer").html(data);
                   }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: What's the question? Also, if you have error messages please include them.

Comment: I don't get an error message.  The issue is under the else{function(changecmnow);} part of function 1.  I don't think that's how it is supposed to be called, but I don't know how else to call it if the user doesn't select the create radio option.

Comment: if you just want to invoke the function, why not just `else { changecmnow(); }`

Comment: perfect!  if you can just make that an answer, I'll select it olore.  I knew it was something simple that I was messing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to invoke the function, why not just

`else { changecmnow(); 
}`